# Importance of Simple Theories

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

In model theory, a complete first-order theory $T$ is said to be *simple* if each type does not fork over some subset of its domain of size at most $|T|$.

**Question (1).** What is the significance of unstable theories in particular simple theories from pure and applied model theory point of views?

**Question (2).** What can a model theorist tell to other mathematicians about a given simple theory which might be interesting for them?

Comment: Simple theories are primarily important because of the ways in which they generalize stable theories. Do you already understand the significance of stable theories?

Comment: Stable theories make more sense because there are some more concrete and natural examples. Independence relation in stable theories also makes more sense for me. But I have no idea about unstable theories including simple theories, NSOP and etc!

Comment: The random graph is a reasonably concrete and natural example of a simple unstable theory. The other classic examples, which have a more algebraic flavor, are psuedo-finite fields and ACFA (the theory of algebraically closed fields with a generic automorphism). For lots more examples in every part of the model-theoretic map, take a look at [forkinganddividing.com](http://forkinganddividing.com).